# MultiIndex DataFrame sorting order after columns stacking to Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, multi-index, lexicographic

Problems during sort_index after DataFrame stack application:

I have an MS Excel singlesheet file which looks like:
[link to table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPBrR.png)

I'v read it in DataFrame and received an expected result:

```
df_test = pd.read_excel(io = path_test_xlsx, header = 0, index_col = 0) 
       US  AR   QA
Date                   
2015-01-01   1  10  100
2016-01-01   2  20  200
2017-01-01   3  30  300
```

Then I stacked it to Series like this:

```
ser_test = df_test.stack()
ser_test.index.names = ['Date', 'Country']
Date        Country
2015-01-01  US           1
            AR          10
            QA         100
2016-01-01  US           2
            AR          20
            QA         200
2017-01-01  US           3
            AR          30
            QA         300
```

Next step is to sort Series by **Country** and then by **Date**. So I tried this:

```
print(ser_test.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date']))
Date        Country
2015-01-01  US           1
2016-01-01  US           2
2017-01-01  US           3
2015-01-01  AR          10
2016-01-01  AR          20
2017-01-01  AR          30
2015-01-01  QA         100
2016-01-01  QA         200
2017-01-01  QA         300
```

Seems to me the problem is in stacking procedure, because next list of manipulations drove me to success:

```
df_test_reseted = ser_test.reset_index(level = 'Country')
ser_test_reseted = df_test_reseted.set_index('Country', append = True).squeeze()
print(ser_test_reseted.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date']))
Date        Country
2015-01-01  AR          10
2016-01-01  AR          20
2017-01-01  AR          30
2015-01-01  QA         100
2016-01-01  QA         200
2017-01-01  QA         300
2015-01-01  US           1
2016-01-01  US           2
2017-01-01  US           3
```

Is stack procedure really leads to ignoring lexicographical order or I've done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems bug because sorting is by labels, not by levels.
If recreate `MultiIndex` it working nice:

```
print (ser_test.index.labels)
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]

print (ser_test.index.levels)
[['2015-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01'], ['US', 'AR', 'QA']]

ser_test.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(ser_test.index.tolist(), names=['Date', 'Country'])
print(ser_test.sort_index(level = ['Country', 'Date']))
Date        Country
2015-01-01  AR          10
2016-01-01  AR          20
2017-01-01  AR          30
2015-01-01  QA         100
2016-01-01  QA         200
2017-01-01  QA         300
2015-01-01  US           1
2016-01-01  US           2
2017-01-01  US           3
dtype: int64
```

Another idea is use this trick - convert Series to one column `DataFrame` and select by `0` in last step:

```
print(ser_test.to_frame().sort_index(level=['Country', 'Date'])[0])
Date        Country
2015-01-01  AR          10
2016-01-01  AR          20
2017-01-01  AR          30
2015-01-01  QA         100
2016-01-01  QA         200
2017-01-01  QA         300
2015-01-01  US           1
2016-01-01  US           2
2017-01-01  US           3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: We are possibly right - this is a particular **Series** problem. Because modifying
`ser_test = df_test.stack(dropna = False)`
on
`ser_test = df_test.stack(dropna = False).to_frame()`
leads to expecting _sort index_ procedure result